# Select columns from a csv file based on user input

Tags: python, csv, datetime, plot, user-input

I am new to Python and I want to make a small program that takes from the user column name or multiple columns name that needed to be plot versus the time.

consider the column names : "time", "c2", "c3","c4", "c5","c6"

the column name needs to be selected from a csv file as a user input to plot a time series curve, However, it did not work for me. Do you have any Idea or similar codes to share?

The code I am using to plot the curves shown below, note that all the columns in the csv file are plotted versus the time column which has been written in epoch and I converted to human readable time later.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 5)
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

# import the csv file and epoch time conversion 
df = pd.read_csv(.csv',parse_dates=['time'], date_parser=lambda epoch: pandas.to_datetime(epoch, unit='s'))
print(df)

# make sure the time column is actually time format
df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

# set time as the index
df.set_index('time',inplace=True)
df.plot(linewidth=2, fontsize=12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably going to need a bit more information than this to try and help.

Are you using a Web framework to be able to draw your plots like Flask or Django?

CSV files are pretty easy to read with column headings as field identifiers using the csv module.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Hopefully the answers are there for you.

Comment: Thank you, I will post the code I am using for more details. Check the edited question please

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to use the [CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module and matplotlib.

[Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/contents.html) has a time series example. [e.g. 1](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/time_series_histogram.html#sphx-glr-gallery-statistics-time-series-histogram-py). You can also look at the other kinds of plots the library can do [over here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index.html).

It is hard to recommend a method without knowing what kind of data you are working with and what needs to be done.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I posted the code I am using